# On adding a class, .click does not trigger - Using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I added a span with a class, but .click does not trigger.

Adding a span class code

```
var TA = '<span class="TS" id="'+$('#TT').attr('value')+'" style=" color:#fff; margin-left:5px; font-family:arial; font-size:12px">* '+$('#TT').attr('value')+'</span>';
$('#QLT').append(TA);
```

This adds a span .TS to a div .TX. I want to trigger .TS using .click, the code

```
  $('.TS').click(function() {
   alert("ok");

  });
```

But this does not trigger.  What is wrong, Appreciate all assistance.

Thanks
Jean

Comment: Make sure the handler is bound after the element has been added to the page. Alternatively, you can use live() (http://api.jquery.com/live) to bind events to elements that aren't in the DOM yet.

Comment: Could we just concentrate on the problem at hand please...I need a solution to it.
- Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably defined the click handler *before* you did `$('#QLT').append(TA)`. Thus the click handler didn't know about the new element with class `.TS` when it was bound.

You can manually re-bind it, or use jQuery's cool [live](http://api.jquery.com/live/) function, which will automatically bind when a new element with class `TS` is inserted into the DOM:

```
$('.TS').live('click', function() {
   alert("ok");
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

[It looks like your code is working fine.](http://jsfiddle.net/sdleihssirhc/VqjpN/)

Maybe when you're clicking, you're not actually clicking on the *text* in the span. I think that messes things up sometimes, with click handlers.